# Login/Signup effects for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

During signup, it directly checks into the server and validates if the email/username is taken. How can this be done, any tutorial would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be:

Use `UITextFieldDelegate` to check when the user has ended the editing of that email `UITextField`. Get the email address and send it to your server to check if its available or not. Then show the error if needed according to the response of your server.

Answer (score 0):

What you are lookin for is called validation,
Try this [US2FormValidator](https://github.com/ustwo/US2FormValidator).

This looks similar to yours.

Also,There are many iOS validator available on Git.

Answer (score 0):

First set delete of your userIDTextField. and implement below delegate method -

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  // Start showing UIActivityIndicator 
  // implement block base web service call to check your user id availability. I will recommended NSURLConnection wrapper base block - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914480/nsurlconnection-with-blocks 


// on results stop activity and show your desire image icon  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type this code into viewDidLoad. This code calls checkEmailMethod when your textField is changed (even backward key pressed).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    ....
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkEmailMethod) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

Then define checkEmailMethod below;

```
- (void)checkEmailMethod{
     //---Send your textField's text to the server
}
```